# regular expression in c is not working properly

Tags: c, regex

I want to match `" 16KQGN579677 PT  "`

This is my attempt:

```
^([A-Z0-9]{2}+)([A-Z]{4}+)([0-9]{1,6}+)([ ]{0,5}+)([A-Z]{1,4}+).*"
```

And this is the code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    regex_t str;
    int reti;
    char msgbuf[100];

    /* need to match this circuit(16KQGN579677 PT) */

     reti=regcomp(&str,"^([A-Z0-9]{2}+)([A-Z]{4}+)([0-9]{1,6}+)([ ]{0,5}+)([A-Z]{1,4}+).*",  0);

       if( reti )
       { 
      fprintf(stderr, "Could not compile regex\n"); 
      exit(1);
       }

    /* need to match this circuit(16KQGN579677 PT) */

    reti = regexec(&str, "16KQGN579677 PT", 0, NULL, 0);
    if( !reti ){
           puts("Match");
           }
    else if( reti == REG_NOMATCH ){
            puts("No match");
           }
    else   {
           regerror(reti, &str, msgbuf, sizeof(msgbuf));
           fprintf(stderr, "Regex match failed: %s\n", msgbuf);
           exit(1);
           }
regfree(&regex);
    return 0;
}
```

what is wrong with the regex in the code?

Comment: have you tried : `^([A-Z0-9]{2}+)([A-Z]{4}+)([0-9]{1,6}+)([ ]{0,5}+)([A-Z]{1,4}+)$` ?

Comment: I don't think `{2}+` is valid. The possesive modifier only makes sense after `{min,max}` or `{min,}`.

Comment: Thanks,it worked using $ and REG_EXTENDED in the flag instead of  "0"

Comment: @Barmar: if it is like PCRE, `{2}+` is only redundant (and useless) but not invalid.

Comment: Why does the post `" 16KQGN579677 PT  "` begin/end with spaces, but code `"16KQGN579677 PT"` does not?

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
([0-9]{2}\w+\s+[A-Z]{1,4})

Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «([0-9]{2}\w+\s+[\w]{2})»
   Match a single character in the range between “0” and “9” «[0-9]{2}»
      Exactly 2 times «{2}»
   Match a single character that is a “word character” (letters, digits, and underscores) «\w+»
      Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
   Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, and line breaks) «\s+»
      Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
   Match a single character that is a “word character” (letters, digits, and underscores) «[\w]{2}»
      Exactly 2 times «{2}»
```